# Swift superclass property/method access: self vs super

Tags: swift, inheritance

In swift, it seems that superclass's `property` or `method` can be accessed through both `self` and `super` without any compile issue.

I do know that when you need to `override` superclass's `property` or `method`, it is mandatory to use `super` to disambiguate.

But when you simply want to access shared method from superclass, which one is more appropriate?

I tend to prefer `super` since I personally think it makes a more readable code but not sure what the best practice is.

Thank you!

Comment: How about just omit the explicit `self`?

Comment: @jtbandes I personally prefer to make my intention explicit whenever I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If method is `overridden`,then self can be used to access method in a subclass otherwise for accessing method of a super class from a base class best practice is to use `super`.

Comment: FYI super cannot be used outside of a class members.